# How to sorting with attrgetter from common foreign key attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
doc_skai = DocSKAI.objects.all()
doc_added = DocAddedSKAI.objects.all()
result_list = sorted(chain(doc_skai, doc_added),key=attrgetter('???'), reverse=True)
```

both doc_skai and doc_added have foreign key with model Document, and Document model have a field of 'published_date'.

How can I sort the result list from the published_date of Document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a lambda-expression:

```
doc_skai = DocSKAI.objects.all()
doc_added = DocAddedSKAI.objects.all()
result_list = sorted(
    chain(doc_skai, doc_added),
    key=lambda x: x.document.published_date,
    reverse=True
)
```

But this will result in the so-called *N+1* problem: for each `DocSKAI` and `DocAddedSKAI`, you will each time fetch the related document.

You can boost efficiency by selecting the related document with [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
doc_skai = DocSKAI.objects.select_related('document')
doc_added = DocAddedSKAI.objects.select_related('document')
result_list = sorted(
    chain(doc_skai, doc_added),
    key=lambda x: x.document.published_date,
    reverse=True
)
```

This will load all the data of the relevant document, which might load a lot of data. We can also work with an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import F

doc_skai = DocSKAI.objects.annotate(published=F('document__published_date'))
doc_added = DocAddedSKAI.objects.annotate(published=F('document__published_date'))
result_list = sorted(
    chain(doc_skai, doc_added),
    key=attrgetter('published'),
    reverse=True
)
```

That being said, it is not clear to me why you have two different models named `DocSKAI` and `DocAddedSKAI`. It looks like it might be better to merge these into a single model with perhaps a boolean attribute `added`.

Comment: Wow thanks man, it works like a charm! i have so much to learn. Actually doc_skai and doc_added is two different models with doc_added have foreign relation to doc_skai, its like a comment to a post